# changing bootstrap 4 navbar breaking point

Tags: css

I was trying to upgrade my css template from Bootstrap3.x to Bootstrap 4

I noticed that in the new version, the navbar bar menu has 3 breaking point option for collapse,

```
navbar-expand = collapse on xs widths <576px
navbar-expand-sm = collapse on sm widths <768px
navbar-expand-lg = collapse on lg widths <1200px
```

In B3 version,  we can manually change the widths pixel by modify the style by css.

Dose any one know how I can change the breaking point in Bootstrap4?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Bootstrap 4 navbar breakpoint using the `navbar-toggleable-*` classes.

Example: https://www.codeply.com/go/GVsytKbMkV

Or if you're trying to use a custom breakpoint, then you can try something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1300px){
    .navbar-expand-custom {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-nav {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-right: .5rem;
        padding-left: .5rem;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-collapse {
        display: flex!important;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Examples:

- [Custom breakpoint](https://www.codeply.com/go/J70zkpygvk)
- [Navbar breakpoint examples](https://www.codeply.com/go/n4Pn4aB695)

Comment: Thanks for answering I will give it a try and get feedback later

Comment: If my solution solved your problem, can you please mark it as the answer? Thanks :)